# Spring, Stomp: How to avoid multiple subscriptions to same destination by same user

Tags: spring, stomp

I'm using Spring 4.2 websockets with stomp on the serverside.
Client uses stomp.js.
I noticed that it is possible for a user to subscribe the same topic-destination multiple times. When a message is delivered to this destination, the user receives it multiple times too.

1. Why is this possible? What would be a use case for this?
2. How can I avoid it? The @SubscribeMapping is called AFTER the subscription and I cannot cancel it.

Comment: I would advise using your unique identifier for your user as the subscription ID when subscribing to a topic/destination using stomp JS. This prevents the autogeneration of subscriptionIds on each subscribe to the topic so you will only have one subscription per topic per user session:

`function subscribe(destination, accountId, callbackHandler) {
            if (null !== stompClient) {
                stompClient.subscribe(destination, function(message) {
                    callbackHandler(message);
                }, {id: accountId});
            }
        }`

Comment: (7 years later) why couldn't this be prevented in the client?